# Why is my Organizer tag not awarded

Tags: support, badges

I have recently edited a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885887/add-class-when-input-is-valid-in-angularjs) where I added two extra tags to the question and the edit has been approved.

I thought I just retagged a question, but the badge Organizer was not given.

Comment: Be patient. Badges are not awarded immediately. You have it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have been awarded the badge. You can see it from [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer?userid=4260544):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer?userid=4260544
```